# PostgreSQL : Querying totals for last 4 weeks and comparing the results to the previous 4 week period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns four and eight week totals/averages. While this is useful, I'm more interested in evaluating performance over the last four weeks and how that data compares to the previous four week period (i.e. eight weeks prior). Any and all help would be tremendously appreciated.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS auto_applicants_4_weeks
   ,(SELECT ROUND(AVG (cjs.score):: numeric,1) 
     FROM candidate_jobs c
              LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
              LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
      WHERE (cjs.date_completed>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '4 weeks') 
               and cjs.date_completed < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
               and o.vertical = 'Auto'
               and cjs.is_completed = 'True'
                  GROUP BY o.vertical) as four_week_smartrank_auto_average
 ,(SELECT COUNT (*) 
     FROM candidate_jobs c
            LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
     WHERE (c.created_at>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '8 weeks') 
            and c.created_at < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
            and o.vertical = 'Auto'
                GROUP BY o.vertical) as auto_applicants_eight_weeks
 ,(SELECT ROUND(AVG (cjs.score):: numeric,1) 
     FROM candidate_jobs c
             LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
             LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
     WHERE (cjs.date_completed>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '8 weeks') 
        and cjs.date_completed < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        and o.vertical = 'Auto'
        and cjs.is_completed = 'True'
            GROUP BY o.vertical) as eight_week_smartrank_auto_average
 ,(SELECT COUNT (c.id) 
       FROM candidate_jobs c
               LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
       WHERE (c.created_at>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '4 weeks') 
               and c.created_at < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
               and o.crm_id = '001U000001aEIuuIAG'
              GROUP BY o.crm_id )as dealership_auto_applicants_4_weeks
 ,(SELECT ROUND(AVG (cjs.score):: numeric,1) 
      FROM candidate_jobs c
              LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
              LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
        WHERE (cjs.date_completed>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '4 weeks') 
              and cjs.date_completed < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
              and o.crm_id = '001U000001aEIuuIAG'
              and cjs.is_completed = 'True'
              GROUP BY o.crm_id) as dealership_smartrank_avg_4_weeks
 ,(SELECT COUNT (c.id) 
      FROM candidate_jobs c
              LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
      WHERE (c.created_at>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '8 weeks') 
              and c.created_at < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
              and o.crm_id = '001U000001aEIuuIAG'
             GROUP BY o.crm_id )as dealership_auto_applicants_8_weeks
 ,(SELECT ROUND(AVG (cjs.score):: numeric,1) 
 FROM candidate_jobs c
          LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
          LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
 WHERE (cjs.date_completed>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '8 weeks') 
         and cjs.date_completed < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
         and o.crm_id = '001U000001aEIuuIAG'
         and cjs.is_completed = 'True'
         GROUP BY o.crm_id) as dealership_smartrank_avg_8_weeks
FROM candidate_jobs c
       LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
 WHERE (c.created_at>= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '4 weeks') 
        and c.created_at < date_trunc('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        and o.vertical = 'Auto'
        GROUP BY o.vertical
```

Comment: Holy wall of SQL, batman... :) Do you think you could boil it down to a somewhat simpler example of what the actual problem is? Rewriting that entire SQL statement would take a while.

Comment: Sure thing! I guess my question is based on whether or not it is possible to create something similar to a flashback query that is available in Oracle.

Comment: And what is the question? Are you receiving errors? What does this SQL currently result and your desired result? Data input/output would be helpful too for [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.